# crosstab queries on mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How to make a query with mongodb on two (ot maybe more) data tables. For example, if I have a table like this:

```
var UserModel   = new Schema({
      email:{ type: String, required: true, index:{unique:true}},
      password:{type:String},
      name:{ type: String, required: true}
});
```

And other like this:

```
 var TicketModel    = new Schema({
     user_id:{ type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User', required: true},
     date:{ type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now},
     money_earned:{ type: Number, required: true},
     status:{type:String, required: true, enum: ['not_confirm', 'on_process', 'earned'], default: 'not_confirm'},
 });
```

And I want to make a query that return all the name, email and money_earned of all the users that have a ticket with status "not_confirm".

I am using node.js, and the first thing I thought was:

```
 router.get('/getNotConfirm', function(req, res){
      ticketsDB.getTickets({status:'not_confirm'}, function(tickets){
           var or = {};
           or.$or = [];
           for(var i in tickets)
                or.$or.push({_id:tickets[i].user_id});
           usersDB.getUsers(or, function(users){
                var to_return = [];
                for(var t in tickets)
                     for(var u in users)
                          if(tickets[t].users_id == users[u]._id)
                               to_return.push({name:users[u].name, email:users[u].email, earned:tickets[t].money_earned});
                res.send(to_return);
           });
      });
 });
```

I think it could work... but the nested for loops make of it a poor idea (I think)... Is there any (implemented directly by mongoose or mongodb) way to make this??
Thank you very much.

Comment: You need async looping control here. See [async](https://github.com/caolan/async). I really wish you had posted for an embedded architecture instead. I had such high hopes for showing how to work with this under and embedded structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try use populate, for example:

```
Ticket.find(query).populate('user').exec(function(ticket){
    "..."
})
```

See moar info here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Thank you @siavolt. It is what I was looking for, something simple and effective. Sorry don´t answer before, I needed make a test, and I couldn´t until today. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the usersDB.getUsers function is asynchronous. So your for loop does not wait for the function to complete. You should use the async library (have a look to the each function): https://github.com/caolan/async